# How to print last line in a list in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, list, line

```
import random

s = []

for i in range(14):
    s.append(random.randint(0,5))

print(s)
```

how i just print last line in a list? Because Python print me s like this:

`[3]`

`[3, 0]`

`[3, 0, 3]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5, 5]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1]`

`[3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1, 4]`  <- this is the only line I want Python print me..

Please help me.

And another question...
How i change this program:

```
for i in s:
   if i < 1:
      print ("It's all good.")
   else:
      print("Not good")
```

that he will print me "Not good" when at least one of numbers in list is 0?

Comment: it doesn't, your print must be inisde the loop. if it was indeed a list of lists, you would `print(s[-1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost certainly doing this:

```
import random

s = []

for i in range(14):
    s.append(random.randint(0,5))

    print(s)
```

Instead, change it to this:

```
import random

s = []

for i in range(14):
    s.append(random.randint(0,5))

print(s)
```

In Python, [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) is significant, so if you have your print statement indented inside your for loop, it will be called each time through the loop. If you have it indented at the same level as the `for ...` it will only execute once after the loop has finished completely.

As to the second question regarding:

```
for i in s:
   if i < 1:
      print ("It's all good.")
   else:
      print("Not good")
```

I am not sure where you want to place the logic you are looking for, but you can test if **"at least one of numbers in list is 0"** with:

```
if 0 in s:
   print("Not good")
```

You should have this check outside of your for loop though, because this check need only be performed once per list, rather than once per value in the list.

Comment: @Bababo I would be happy to. But if it is an unrelated question, or one that requires a lot of details, you would be better off posting a new question on this site. What is the question?

Comment: @Bababo Haha, see my updated answer, which is exactly the same thing. Glad you were able to come to the solution on your own:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) You are very helpfull! I tried like 500 times, and at least 501. try was good!